# Custom IUserAuthRepository with Servicestack

Tags: neo4j, .net-core, servicestack

I'm in the process of trying to set up a server for a personal project. I'm using ServiceStack.Core with a Neo4j graph database as my persistence layer.

I would like to set up user authentication using my graph database as the user auth repository. There is no existing implementation of IUserAuthRepository for Neo4j as far as I can tell, meaning that I will have to create my own. Unfortunately, I have found very little documentation on this interface and how to correctly implement it.

So, I have a few questions:

- Does there exist any kind of tutorial or other documentation on how to correctly implement my own IUserAuthRepository?
- The CreateUserAuth method is supposed to take a password. What if a user logged in using Facebook or some other service and does not have a password?
- Would it make more sense to just use Redis for authentication (with RedisAuthRepository), using the userAuthId to look up users in my graph db? Are there any major pitfalls to doing something like this? If I do go this route, how do I hook into the registration process to ensure that I create a user in the graph DB whenever a new user is registered?

Answer (score 1):

There aren't any docs on implementing `IUserAuthRepository`, it's an interface with a lot of [reference implementations](http://docs.servicestack.net/authentication-and-authorization#user-auth-repository). Easiest way would be to follow the implementation that works similar to neo4j.

The `IUserAuthRepository` [stores 2 tables](https://github.com/ServiceStack/ServiceStack/blob/master/src/ServiceStack/Auth/UserAuth.cs), `UserAuth` master table and `UserAuthDetails` child table which is where all OAuth providers like Facebook maintain info received when authenticating with them. The password field is used for `CredentialsAuthProvider`.

You can handle different events during registration and authentication with the [Session and Auth Events](http://docs.servicestack.net/sessions#session-events).

Comment: Do you happen to know if `IUserAuth.Id`, `IUserAuthDetails.Id` and `IUserAuthDetails.UserAuthId` are used anywhere outside of the User Auth Repository? An auto-incrementing int id doesn't really work well with Neo4j, for a number of reasons. It would make more sense to have `UserAuth` be indexed by a UUID, and to reach the `UserAuthDetails` nodes by traversing the graph from the `UserAuth` node (and vice versa). I can accomplish this by setting `UserAuth.RefIdStr` to my UUID and ignoring all other `Id` fields, but I'm worried that other Servicestack code might depend on these Id values somehow